# Convert structured array to regular NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

The answer will be very obvious I think, but I don't see it at the moment.

**How can I convert a record array back to a regular ndarray?**

Suppose I have following simple structured array:

```
x = np.array([(1.0, 4.0,), (2.0, -1.0)], dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

then I want to convert it to:

```
array([[ 1.,  4.],
       [ 2., -1.]])
```

I tried `asarray` and `astype`, but that didn't work.

**UPDATE (solved: float32 (f4) instead of float64 (f8))**

OK, I tried the solution of Robert (`x.view(np.float64).reshape(x.shape + (-1,))` ), and with a simple array it works perfectly. But with the array I wanted to convert it gives a strange outcome:

```
data = np.array([ (0.014793682843446732, 0.006681123282760382, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0008984912419691682, 0.0, 0.013475529849529266, 0.0, 0.0),
       (0.014793682843446732, 0.006681123282760382, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0008984912419691682, 0.0, 0.013475529849529266, 0.0, 0.0),
       (0.014776384457945824, 0.006656022742390633, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0008901208057068288, 0.0, 0.013350814580917358, 0.0, 0.0),
       (0.011928378604352474, 0.002819152781739831, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0012627150863409042, 0.0, 0.018906937912106514, 0.0, 0.0),
       (0.011928378604352474, 0.002819152781739831, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001259754877537489, 0.0, 0.01886274479329586, 0.0, 0.0),
       (0.011969991959631443, 0.0028706740122288465, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0007433745195157826, 0.0, 0.011164642870426178, 0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('a_soil', '<f4'), ('b_soil', '<f4'), ('Ea_V', '<f4'), ('Kcc', '<f4'), ('Koc', '<f4'), ('Lmax', '<f4'), ('malfarquhar', '<f4'), ('MRN', '<f4'), ('TCc', '<f4'), ('Vcmax_3', '<f4')])
```

and then:

```
data_array = data.view(np.float).reshape(data.shape + (-1,))
```

gives:

```
In [8]: data_array
Out[8]: 
array([[  2.28080997e-20,   0.00000000e+00,   2.78023241e-27,
          6.24133580e-18,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.28080997e-20,   0.00000000e+00,   2.78023241e-27,
          6.24133580e-18,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.21114197e-20,   0.00000000e+00,   2.55866881e-27,
          5.79825816e-18,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.04776835e-23,   0.00000000e+00,   3.47457730e-26,
          9.32782857e-17,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.04776835e-23,   0.00000000e+00,   3.41189244e-26,
          9.20222417e-17,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  2.32706550e-23,   0.00000000e+00,   4.76375305e-28,
          1.24257748e-18,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

which is an array with other numbers and another shape. What did I do wrong?

Comment: np.asanyarray(x) will maintain the complex dtype for each column else np.array(x.tolist())

Comment: You need to replace `np.float` with `data.dtype[0]`. Please, update your question posting the solution at the end, so it is more clear for the reader.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
[~]
|5> x = np.array([(1.0, 4.0,), (2.0, -1.0)], dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8')])

[~]
|6> x.view(np.float64).reshape(x.shape + (-1,))
array([[ 1.,  4.],
       [ 2., -1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose this doesn't make a copy of the array?

Comment: @joris: Your array contains single-precision (32 bit) floating point numbers.  To reinterpret the same memory as an unstructured array, use `.view(np.float32)` in the above code.

Comment: @joris, correct, it does not make a copy. It is just a view on top of the memory in the original array.

Comment: There is no need for a tuple construction: `reshape(x.shape + (-1,))` can be simplified as `reshape(x.shape, -1)`.  I updated the answer.

Comment: @EOL I consider that an undocumented misfeature that makes the code less consistent and harder to understand. Please consider reverting.

Comment: @RobertKern: It is indeed not documented in the `reshape()` documentation string. However, it is used in many places in the official documentation, so I take it it is quite official (one can for instance find many instances of `reshape(i, j, k)` at http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List). I asked the NumPy community to clarify this (http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/2110).

Comment: @EOL I still consider `reshape(i,j,k)` to be an inconsistent misfeature to avoid, but it's been around long enough that I don't militate for its removal. I've never seen `reshape(some_tuple, j)` before in code or in documentation. In any case, I do not wish to appear as if I am recommending it.

Comment: @EOL Actually `reshape(some_tuple, -1)` simply doesn't work. I don't know what version of numpy you are using in which it does work. I am reverting.

Comment: @RobertKern: Right, the "(tuple, int)" form does not work. In fact, I meant what I wrote in the comment: "reshape(int, int,…)", which would be here `x.view(np.float64).reshape(len(x), -1))`.  I think that this is more legible than the tuple concatenation. However, I will leave your original post as is, because of the absence of a clear cut recommendation on the use of `reshape()` with integer arguments.

Answer (score 49):

The simplest method is probably

```
x.view((float, len(x.dtype.names)))
```

(`float` must generally be replaced by the type of the elements in `x`: `x.dtype[0]`). This assumes that all the elements have the same type.

This method gives you the regular `numpy.ndarray` version in a single step (as opposed to the two steps required by the `view(…).reshape(…)` method.

Comment: I would add an improvement: `x.view((x.dtype[0], len(x.dtype.names)))`. So, one can even define a function that does this, since everything is parametrised.

Comment: You mentioned that the *Cookbook* has a few efficient methods. Would you mind pointing out **where**. I am not sure how to find them.

Comment: The link that was in the answer became invalid. I cannot find the page it was originally referring to.

Comment: Oh, OK then. I would still recommend replacing `float` with `x.dtype[0]`.

Comment: I've been using this method for a while now; unfortunately now I'm getting "FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you may be viewing or writing to an array returned by selecting multiple fields in a structured array.
This code may break in numpy 1.13 because this will return a view instead of a copy -- see release notes for details." Any thoughts how to deal with that?

Comment: I don't foresee any real problem. You just need to be aware of the change (which is actually [slated for NumPy 1.14](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.13.0-notes.rst#future-changes)) so as to make sure that your code does not break. If the warning bothers you, you can [silence it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.13.0-notes.rst#future-changes).

Comment: This does not work for me in Numpy 1.14. Assume I have the following structured array: `arr = np.array([(105.0, 34.0, 145.0, 217.0)], dtype=[('a', 'f4'), ('b', 'f4'), ('c', 'f4'), ('d', 'f4')])`. Then trying to convert the 4-tuple inside into a regular array via `out = arr[0].view((np.float32, len(arr.dtype.names)))` results in `ValueError: Changing the dtype of a 0d array is only supported if the itemsize is unchanged`.

Comment: Have you tried what this response suggests, namely `arr.view((np.float32, len(arr.dtype.names))`? (If you want the first line of 4 floats, you can _append_ `[0]`.) This works with Numpy 1.13.3, on my machine.

Comment: Does not work for mixed datatypes ...

Comment: Indeed, as indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 18):

In conjunction with changes on how it handle multi-field indexing `numpy` has provided two new functions that can help in converting to/from structured arrays:

In `numpy.lib.recfunctions`, these are `structured_to_unstructured` and `unstructured_to_structured`.  `repack_fields` is another new function.

From the `1.16` release notes

> multi-field views return a view instead of a copy
>
> Indexing a structured array with multiple fields, e.g., arr[['f1', 'f3']], returns a view into the original array instead of a copy. The returned view will often have extra padding bytes corresponding to intervening fields in the original array, unlike before, which will affect code such as arr[['f1', 'f3']].view('float64'). This change has been planned since numpy 1.7. Operations hitting this path have emitted FutureWarnings since then. Additional FutureWarnings about this change were added in 1.12.
>
> To help users update their code to account for these changes, a number of functions have been added to the numpy.lib.recfunctions module which safely allow such operations. For instance, the code above can be replaced with structured_to_unstructured(arr[['f1', 'f3']], dtype='float64'). See the “accessing multiple fields” section of the user guide.

Comment: Here's a link to the [accessing multiple fields](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html?highlight=accessing%20multiple%20fields#accessing-multiple-fields) section of the user guide.

Comment: This is a better answer than the selected one. Using `.view(float)` doe not allow to extract and merge a *subset of fields*, whereas `structured_to_unstructured` does

Comment: Best answer! It works fine
`from numpy.lib.recfunctions import structured_to_unstructured`
`structured_to_unstructured(X)`

Comment: Great answer. This feels like the most "official" way of doing this. Great for reading point cloud data from a PLY file using the `plyfile` library, for example.

Answer (score 15):

```
np.array(x.tolist())
array([[ 1.,  4.],
      [ 2., -1.]])
```

but maybe there is a better method...

Comment: This is slow, as you first convert an efficiently packed NumPy array to a regular Python list.  The official method is much faster (see my answer).

Comment: This is the easiest to remember... It's surprising there is no `x.toArray()` method...

Comment: Don't make python lists when you don't have to, they're much more expensive.

Comment: This is indeed slow, but the only answer that works reliably. The other ones do not work for me (numpy 1.14.x).

Comment: Efficiency/speed is not always that important. IMHO this solution is much more readable than the efficient-yet-obscure `view` approach.

Comment: This method works when the structured array has multiple data types, the other methods fail under this situation. Very useful for unit tests where speed isn't important, just getting a comparison to work is.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution using the function **rec2array** of [root_numpy](https://github.com/scikit-hep/root_numpy):

```
np_array = rec2array(x)
```

**root_numpy** is actually deprecated but the **rec2array**  code is useful anyway (source [here](https://github.com/scikit-hep/root_numpy/blob/e0dd5898a6f7c25e1c80c12bd92abc959b851666/root_numpy/_utils.py)):

```
def rec2array(rec, fields=None):

  simplify = False

  if fields is None:
      fields = rec.dtype.names
  elif isinstance(fields, string_types):
      fields = [fields]
      simplify = True

  # Creates a copy and casts all data to the same type
  arr = np.dstack([rec[field] for field in fields])

  # Check for array-type fields. If none, then remove outer dimension.
  # Only need to check first field since np.dstack will anyway raise an
  # exception if the shapes don't match
  # np.dstack will also fail if fields is an empty list
  if not rec.dtype[fields[0]].shape:
      arr = arr[0]

  if simplify:
      # remove last dimension (will be of size 1)
      arr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[:-1])

  return arr
```