# Remove `dtype` fields from structured array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using a package containing a function that returns a list of polygon vertices (let's call it `polylist`). Each element of this list (that have tens of thousands elements) has the following structure

```
p0 = polylist[0] = 
array([(137.487773, 65.338638), 
       (138.29366, 64.992167),
       (140.625, 64.992167), 
       ...,
       (140.625, 65.402088), 
       dtype=[('ra', '>f8'), ('dec', '>f8')])
```

To plot the elements in `polylist`, I want to use [`matplotlib.patches.Polygon`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon) or [`matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection).

But both `Polygon` and `PolyCollection` need the vertices to be a 2d numpy array of shape `(N,2)`. So I need to convert `p0` into something like

```
p0 = 
array([[137.487773, 65.338638], 
       [138.29366, 64.992167],
       [140.625, 64.992167], 
       ...,
       [140.625, 65.402088]])
```

If I do `np.array(p0, dtype=float)` I get only `p0['ra']`

```
array([137.487773,  138.29366,  140.625,  140.625, ..., 140.009968])
```

To ways came to my mind

```
np.array((v['ra'], v['dec'])).T
```

or

```
np.vstack((v['ra'], v['dec'])).T
```

Is there any better way or any numpy function to do it?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957380/convert-structured-array-to-regular-numpy-array

Comment: @atomh33ls Thanks. I did search a lot, but didn't find a solution. Probably I should mark my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
p0.view(('>f8', 2))
```

See [`view` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) and also http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray