# are numpy record/structure arrays restricted to containing numpy voids?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have a complicated set of data that I have to do distance calculations on.  Each record in the data set contains many different data types so a record array or structured array appears to be the way to go.  The problem is when I have to do my distance calculations, the scipy spatial distance functions take arrays and the recored array is numpy voids.  How to I make a recored array of numpy arrays instead of numpy voids?  Below is a very simple example of what I'm talking about.

```
import numpy
import scipy.spatial.distance as scidist


input_data = [
    ('340.9', '7548.2', '1192.4', 'set001.txt'),
    ('546.7', '9039.9', '5546.1', 'set002.txt'),
    ('456.3', '2234.8', '2198.8', 'set003.txt'),
    ('332.1', '1144.2', '2344.5', 'set004.txt'),
]

record_array = numpy.array(input_data,
                           dtype=[('d1', 'float64'), ('d2', 'float64'), ('d3', 'float64'), ('file', '|S20')])
```

The following code fails...

```
this_fails_and_makes_me_cry = record_array[['d1', 'd2', 'd3']]
scidist.pdist(this_fails_and_makes_me_cry)
```

I get this error....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/someguy/working_datasets/trial003/scrap.py", line 16, in <module>
    scidist.pdist(record_array[['d1', 'd2', 'd3']])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py", line 1093, in pdist
    raise ValueError('A 2-dimensional array must be passed.');
ValueError: A 2-dimensional array must be passed.
```

The error occurs because this_fails_and_makes_me_cry is an array of numpy.voids.  To get it to work I have to convert each time like this...

```
this_works = numpy.array(map(list, record_array[['d1', 'd2', 'd3']]))
scidist.pdist(this_works)
```

Is it possible to create a record array of numpy arrays to begin with?  Or is a numpy record/structured array restricted to numpy voids?  It would be handy for the record array to contain the data in a format compatible with scipy's spatial distance functions so that I don't have to convert each time.  Is this possible?

Comment: My understanding is that Numpy structured arrays can only contain fields of discrete types (plus fixed lenght strings), so no, you cannot store an array. You could turn that conversion into a function to make it easier... and use some standard way to convert the data to a 2D array (like `array.view`), [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957380/convert-structured-array-to-regular-numpy-array)

Comment: Bummer.  I was hoping that wasn't the case because I have to do this a TON of times due to the large number of distance calculations and the large data set that I have.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this_fails_and_makes_me_cry = record_array[['d1', 'd2', 'd3']]
```

creates a one-dimensional structured array, with fields `d1`, `d2` and `d3`.  `pdist` expects a two-dimensional array.  Here's one way to create that two-dimensional array containing only the `d` fields of `record_array`.

(*Note:*  The following won't work if the fields that you want to use for the distance calculation are not contiguous within the data type of the structured array `record_array`.  See below for an alternative in that case.)

First, we make a new dtype, in which `d1`, `d2` and `d3` become a single field called `d` containing three floating point values:

```
In [61]: dt2 = dtype([('d', 'f8', 3), ('file', 'S20')])
```

Next, use the [`view`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) method to create a view of `record_array` using this dtype:

```
In [62]: rav = record_array.view(dt2)

In [63]: rav
Out[63]: 
array([([340.9, 7548.2, 1192.4], 'set001.txt'),
       ([546.7, 9039.9, 5546.1], 'set002.txt'),
       ([456.3, 2234.8, 2198.8], 'set003.txt'),
       ([332.1, 1144.2, 2344.5], 'set004.txt')], 
      dtype=[('d', '<f8', (3,)), ('file', 'S20')])
```

`rav` is not a copy--it is a view of the same block of memory used by `record_array`.

Now access field `d` to get the two-dimensional array:

```
In [64]: d = rav['d']

In [65]: d
Out[65]: 
array([[  340.9,  7548.2,  1192.4],
       [  546.7,  9039.9,  5546.1],
       [  456.3,  2234.8,  2198.8],
       [  332.1,  1144.2,  2344.5]])
```

`d` can be passed to `pdist`:

```
In [66]: pdist(d)
Out[66]: 
array([ 4606.75875427,  5409.10137454,  6506.81395539,  7584.32432455,
        8522.8149229 ,  1107.27706108])
```

Note that instead of converting `record_array` to `rav`, you could use `dt2` as the data type of `record_array` from the start, and just write `d = record_array['d']`.

---

If the fields in `record_array` that are used for the distance calculation are not contiguous in the structure, you'll first have to pull them out into a new array so they are contiguous:

```
In [83]: arr = record_array[['d1','d2','d3']]
```

Then take a view of `arr` and reshape to make it two-dimensional:

```
In [84]: d = arr.view(np.float64).reshape(-1,3)

In [85]: d
Out[85]: 
array([[  340.9,  7548.2,  1192.4],
       [  546.7,  9039.9,  5546.1],
       [  456.3,  2234.8,  2198.8],
       [  332.1,  1144.2,  2344.5]])
```

You can combine those into a single line, if that's more convenient:

```
In [86]: d = record_array[['d1', 'd2', 'd3']].view(np.float64).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Comment: That is very clever.  I wasn't aware you could do this with numpy.  So the view function is just a different way of formating an existing numpy object without creating a new one?

Comment: Yes; check out http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html

Comment: Thanks.  Also, is it possible to view slices of an array?  What if I wanted to create a view of the first two elements of the record array and another separate view of the last two elements without creating two new numpy objects?  Is that possible?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized numpy slices don't copy the object like python list slices do.