# Convert structured array with various numeric data types to regular array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

Suppose I have a NumPy structured array with various numeric datatypes.  As a basic example,

```
my_data = np.array( [(17, 182.1),  (19, 175.6)],  dtype='i2,f4')
```

How can I cast this into a regular NumPy array of floats?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5957455/2223706), I know I could use

```
np.array(my_data.tolist())
```

but apparently it is slow since you "convert an efficiently packed NumPy array to a regular Python list".

Comment: In that previous question, all the fields were of the same type.

Comment: I wrote [a quick script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/74487ac64c2f69b781d5) to see which of the answers was the fastest for a 30000x3000 array, and they were pretty similar -- JohnZwinck's: 0.30s,  Jaime's: 0.41s, hpaulj's: 0.46s, WarrenWeckesser: 0.47s.  And they all used about 3GB of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily with Pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(my_data).values
array([[  17.       ,  182.1000061],
       [  19.       ,  175.6000061]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (assuming `my_data` is a one-dimensional structured array):

```
In [26]: my_data
Out[26]: 
array([(17, 182.10000610351562), (19, 175.60000610351562)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i2'), ('f1', '<f4')])

In [27]: np.column_stack(my_data[name] for name in my_data.dtype.names)
Out[27]: 
array([[  17.       ,  182.1000061],
       [  19.       ,  175.6000061]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way works:

```
>>> my_data
array([(17, 182.10000610351562), (19, 175.60000610351562)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i2'), ('f1', '<f4')])
>>> n = len(my_data.dtype.names)  # n == 2
>>> my_data.astype(','.join(['f4']*n))
array([(17.0, 182.10000610351562), (19.0, 175.60000610351562)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
>>> my_data.astype(','.join(['f4']*n)).view('f4')
array([  17.       ,  182.1000061,   19.       ,  175.6000061], dtype=float32)
>>> my_data.astype(','.join(['f4']*n)).view('f4').reshape(-1, n)
array([[  17.       ,  182.1000061],
       [  19.       ,  175.6000061]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Warren's answer (which copies data by field):

```
x = np.empty((my_data.shape[0],len(my_data.dtype)),dtype='f4')
for i,n in enumerate(my_data.dtype.names):
    x[:,i]=my_data[n]
```

Or you could iterate by row.  `r` is a tuple.  It has to be converted to a list in order to fill a row of `x`.   With many rows and few fields this will be slower.

```
for i,r in enumerate(my_data):
    x[i,:]=list(r)
```

It may be instructive to try `x.data=r.data`, and get an error: `AttributeError: not enough data for array`.  `x` data is a buffer with 4 floats.  `my_data` is a buffer with 2 tuples, each of which contains an int and a float (or sequence of [int float int float]).  `my_data.itemsize==6`.  One way or other, the `my_data` has to be converted to all floats, and the tuple grouping removed.

But using `astype` as Jaime shows does work:

```
x.data=my_data.astype('f4,f4').data
```

In quick tests using a 1000 item array with 5 fields, copying field by field is just as fast as using `astype`.