# Why is this data not returning a numpy shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, format

Using NumPy, I am trying to reshape data that looks like the following once loaded:

```
(0.00017299999308306724, 0.00020900000527035445, ... 0.9700180292129517)
```

It has 54 items and I'm trying to ultimately reshape it into a 27x2 array.  It does load as an array but returns a shape of: ()
I have tested with NumPy doing the following:

```
    test = np.arange(54)
    print(test)
    print(test.shape)
    test = test.reshape(27,2)
```

That works as expected, giving an initial shape of (54,) and then a new shape of (27,2).  The data mentioned above does not return a shape and I'm unable to reshape it. 
The test data that does work looks like this when first initialized `[0 1 2 3 ...53]`  Why does the data format look so different (not the types but the [] with spaces vs () with , and how would one go about changing the format so the array may be reshaped?

Comment: Can you provide the code you've used to load your data in?

Comment: did you try first to define `a = np.array([...])`? and then `a.resample(...)`?

Comment: No, I didn't do a resample.  I'm loading data from a large NumPy binary file and grabbing two lines out of there.  That initially returns a len of 2 and a shape of (2,) but each of those records have 54 values.  I can reference them like data[0][n] but when I try to load a single 54 value, record for lack of a better word, I get the problem of returning a shape like () even though I can reference each of the items in the array and it loaded with a call to asarray and other methods.  The only difference I see is the way the data looks in my initial description - thank you so much for your time.

Comment: `()` in Python indicates a `tuple` as opposed to a list.  In `numpy`, this tuple notation is used for an element of a structured array.  What is the `dtype` of the original array?

Comment: Thank you hpaulj - I realized that shortly after posting and called np.tolist within np.asarray and it now gives me a shape.

Comment: I don't think it is the best way but right now calling: new_test = np.asarray(test.tolist()) converts it in such a way that I get a valid shape returned and can then go on to reshape.  I'm not sure why this would be necessary when working with data stored in the NumPy format.

Comment: Chris, hpaulj is right. You seem to be having a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), which you might have gotten from a call to `numpy.genfromtxt`. If your entire array is numeric, you could simply fiddle with the options of `genfromtxt` or [convert](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5957380/2476444) it, if the fields of the records have the same byte interpretation and bytesize.

Comment: Hpaulj & Oliver, thank you.  That appears to be the case - that it is a structured array from data that was converted via genfromtxt.  It is a large data set ~ 8GB in binary format so I'm unsure of how best to convert at the moment but will investigate that - thank you.  The dtype consists of three integers followed by 54 floats per "record".  The integer values are used to locate the data, it is sorted and a separate index file is used to then load chunks of this data at a time as needed.