# Get all columns in a numpy structured array.

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to slice a numpy structured array. 
I have an array

```
>>b
>>array([([11.0, 21.0, 31.0, 0.01], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0]),
       ([41.0, 51.0, 61.0, 0.11], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.1]),
       ([71.0, 81.0, 91.0, 0.21], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 0.2])], 
       dtype=[('fd', '<f8', (4,)), ('av', '<f8', (4,))])
```

And I want to access elements of this to create a new array similar to

```
>>b[:][:,0]
```

to get an array similar to this. (To get all rows in all columns at [0]). (Please don't mind the parenthesis, brackets and dimensions in the following as this is not an output)

```
>>array([([11.0],[1.0]),
  ([41.0],[4.0]),
  ([71.0],[7.0])],
  dtype=[('fd', '<f8', (1,)), ('av', '<f8', (1,))])
```

but I get this error.

```
>>b[:][:,0]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I would like to do this without looping the names in dtype. 
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You access the fields of a structured array by field name.  There isn't a way around this.  Unless the dtypes let you view it in a different way.

Lets call your desire output `c`.

```
In [1061]: b['fd']
Out[1061]: 
array([[  1.10000000e+01,   2.10000000e+01,   3.10000000e+01,
          1.00000000e-02],
       [  4.10000000e+01,   5.10000000e+01,   6.10000000e+01,
          1.10000000e-01],
       [  7.10000000e+01,   8.10000000e+01,   9.10000000e+01,
          2.10000000e-01]])
```

What I think you are trying to do is collect these values for both fields:

```
In [1062]: b['fd'][:,0]
Out[1062]: array([ 11.,  41.,  71.])

In [1064]: c['fd']
Out[1064]: 
array([[ 11.],
       [ 41.],
       [ 71.]])
```

As I just explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090370/901925 the `recfunctions` generally allocate a target array and copy values by field.

So the field iteration solution would be something like:

```
In [1066]: c.dtype
Out[1066]: dtype([('fd', '<f8', (1,)), ('av', '<f8', (1,))])

In [1067]: b.dtype
Out[1067]: dtype([('fd', '<f8', (4,)), ('av', '<f8', (4,))])

In [1068]: d=np.zeros((b.shape), dtype=c.dtype)


In [1070]: for n in b.dtype.names:
    d[n][:] = b[n][:,[0]]

In [1071]: d
Out[1071]: 
array([([11.0], [1.0]), ([41.0], [4.0]), ([71.0], [7.0])], 
      dtype=[('fd', '<f8', (1,)), ('av', '<f8', (1,))])
```

================

Since both fields a floats, I can view `b` as a 2d array; and select the 2 subcolumns with 2d array indexing:

```
In [1083]: b.view((float,8)).shape
Out[1083]: (3, 8)

In [1084]: b.view((float,8))[:,[0,4]]
Out[1084]: 
array([[ 11.,   1.],
       [ 41.,   4.],
       [ 71.,   7.]])
```

Similarly, `c` can be viewed as 2d

```
In [1085]: c.view((float,2))
Out[1085]: 
array([[ 11.,   1.],
       [ 41.,   4.],
       [ 71.,   7.]])
```

And I can, then port the values to a blank `d` with:

```
In [1090]: d=np.zeros((b.shape), dtype=c.dtype)

In [1091]: d.view((float,2))[:]=b.view((float,8))[:,[0,4]]

In [1092]: d
Out[1092]: 
array([([11.0], [1.0]), ([41.0], [4.0]), ([71.0], [7.0])], 
      dtype=[('fd', '<f8', (1,)), ('av', '<f8', (1,))])
```

So, at least in this case, we don't have to do field by field copy.  But I can't say, without testing, which is faster.  In my previous answer I found that field by field copy was relatively fast when dealing with many rows.

Comment: Can you explain how you got c. I cannot seem to find it. Thanks

Comment: `c` is just a copy/paste from your post, your `>>array([([11.0],[1.0]),... ('av', '<f8', (1,))])`.

Comment: I figured out how to do the copy via views.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot.