# Using np.view() with changes to structured arrays in numpy 1.14

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy structured array with a mixed dtype (i.e., floats, ints, and strings). I want to select some of the columns of the array (all of which contain only floats) and then get the sum, by column, of the rows, as a standard numpy array. The initial array takes a form comparable to:

```
some_data = np.array([('foo', 3.5, 2.15), ('bar', 2.8, 5.3), ('baz', 1.2, 3.7)], 
                     dtype=[('col1', '<U20'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8')])
```

For this example, I'd like to take the sum of columns A and B, yielding `np.array([7.5, 11.15])`. With numpy ≤1.13, I could do that as follows:

```
get_cols = ['A', 'B']
desired_sum = np.sum(some_data[get_cols].view(('<f8', len(get_cols))), axis=0)
```

With the release of numpy 1.14, this method now fails with `ValueError: Changing the dtype to a subarray type is only supported if the total itemsize is unchanged`, which is a result of the changes made in [numpy 1.14 to the handling of structured arrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.14.0-notes.rst#multiple-field-indexingassignment-of-structured-arrays). (User bbengfort commented about the FutureWarning given about this change in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171321/2471874).)

In light of these changes to structured arrays, how can I obtain the desired sum from the structured array subset?

Comment: a 'regression'  check https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10387 and other threads for interim solutions until a 'fix' is in place

Comment: @NaN: This particular problem is different from that one - It's not going to be fixed unless a separate issue is reported. In this case, it should be possible to sum the array without incurring a copy

Comment: Issue opened [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10409)

Comment: What version of numpy were you using? What is x in 1.14.x?

Comment: @Eric, the error arises with numpy 1.14.0. In numpy 1.14.x, where x ≥ 1, a FutureWarning is triggered instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [165]: some_data = np.array([('foo', 3.5, 2.15), ('bar', 2.8, 5.3), ('baz', 1.2, 3.7)], dtype=[('col1', '<U20'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8')])
     ...:                      
In [166]: get_cols = ['A','B']
In [167]: some_data[get_cols]
Out[167]: 
array([( 3.5,  2.15), ( 2.8,  5.3 ), ( 1.2,  3.7 )],
      dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8')])
```

Simply reading the field values is fine.  In 1.13 we get a warning

```
In [168]: some_data[get_cols].view(('<f8', len(get_cols)))
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you may be viewing or writing to an array returned by selecting multiple fields in a structured array. 

This code may break in numpy 1.13 because this will return a view instead of a copy -- see release notes for details.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[168]: 
array([[ 3.5 ,  2.15],
       [ 2.8 ,  5.3 ],
       [ 1.2 ,  3.7 ]])
```

With the recommended copy, no warning:

```
In [169]: some_data[get_cols].copy().view(('<f8', len(get_cols)))
Out[169]: 
array([[ 3.5 ,  2.15],
       [ 2.8 ,  5.3 ],
       [ 1.2 ,  3.7 ]])
In [171]: np.sum(_, axis=0)
Out[171]: array([  7.5 ,  11.15])
```

In your original array,

```
dtype([('col1', '<U20'), ('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8')])
```

An `A,B` slice would have the two `f8` items interspersed with the 20U items.  Changing the `view` dtype of such a mix is problematic.  That's why working with a copy is more reliable.

Since `U20` takes up 4*20 bytes, the total `itemsize` is 96, a multiple of 8.  We can convert the whole thing to `f8`, reshape and 'throw-away' the `U20` columns:

```
In [183]: some_data.view('f8').reshape(3,-1)[:,-2:]
Out[183]: 
array([[ 3.5 ,  2.15],
       [ 2.8 ,  5.3 ],
       [ 1.2 ,  3.7 ]])
```

It's not very pretty and I don't recommend it, but it may give some insight into how structured data is arranged.

`view` on a structured array is useful at times, but often a bit tricky to use correctly.

If the 2 numeric fields are usually used together, I'd recommend a compound dtype like:

```
In [184]: some_data = np.array([('foo', [3.5, 2.15]), ('bar', [2.8, 5.3]), ('baz
     ...: ', [1.2, 3.7])], 
     ...:                      dtype=[('col1', '<U20'), ('AB', '<f8',(2,))])
     ...:                      
     ...:                      
In [185]: some_data
Out[185]: 
array([('foo', [ 3.5 ,  2.15]), ('bar', [ 2.8 ,  5.3 ]),
       ('baz', [ 1.2 ,  3.7 ])],
      dtype=[('col1', '<U20'), ('AB', '<f8', (2,))])
In [186]: some_data['AB']
Out[186]: 
array([[ 3.5 ,  2.15],
       [ 2.8 ,  5.3 ],
       [ 1.2 ,  3.7 ]])
```

`genfromtxt` accepts this style of `dtype`.

Comment: While adding `.copy()` in front of view eliminates the FutureWarning from numpy 1.13, that line will still trigger the same ValueError from numpy 1.14.