# Convert a slice of a structured array to regular NumPy array in NumPy 1.14

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

Note 1: None of the answers given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957380/convert-structured-array-to-regular-numpy-array) work in my case.

Note 2: The solution must work in NumPy 1.14.

Assume I have the following structured array:

`arr = np.array([(105.0, 34.0, 145.0, 217.0)], dtype=[('a', 'f4'), ('b', 'f4'), ('c', 'f4'), ('d', 'f4')])`.

Now I'm slicing into the structured data type like so:

`arr2 = arr[['a', 'b']]`

And now I'm trying to convert that slice into a regular array:

`out = arr2[0].view((np.float32, 2))`

which results in

`ValueError: Changing the dtype of a 0d array is only supported if the itemsize is unchanged`

What I would like to get is just a regular array like so:

`[105.0, 34.0]`

Note that this example is simplified in order to be minimal. In my real use case I'm obviously not dealing with an array that holds one element.

I know that this solution works:

`out = np.asarray(list(arr2[0]))`

but I thought there must be a more efficient solution than copying data that is already in a NumPy array into a list and then back into an array. I assume there is a way to stay in NumPy an maybe not actually copy any data at all, I just don't know how.

Comment: Are you looking for `np.array(arr[0].tolist())`?

Comment: @pault yes, but going from structured array to a list and then to an array not an efficient solution :/

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. `arr[0].view((np.float32, len(arr.dtype.names)))` works for me.

Comment: adding to @pault, i can't recreate the error either and my numpy version is 1.11

Comment: @pault which Numpy version are you on? Some behavior around structured arrays changed with 1.14, which is what I'm on

Comment: @Alex could be- I'm using `1.11.2`

Comment: Related: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10752

Comment: @Alex I can't reproduce your error. I am using NumPy 1.14.0.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I messed up my example. The way I had it above was a bit too oversimplified and indeed didn't throw the error. I've made a minor modification to the example and now it definitely throws the error (unfortunately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1d array does convert with `view`:

```
In [270]: arr = np.array([(105.0, 34.0, 145.0, 217.0)], dtype=[('a', 'f4'), ('b','f4'), ('c', 'f4'), ('d', 'f4')])
In [271]: arr
Out[271]: 
array([(105., 34., 145., 217.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f4'), ('d', '<f4')])
In [272]: arr.view('<f4')
Out[272]: array([105.,  34., 145., 217.], dtype=float32)
```

It's when we try to convert a single element, that we get this error:

```
In [273]: arr[0].view('<f4')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-70fbab8f61ba> in <module>()
----> 1 arr[0].view('<f4')

ValueError: Changing the dtype of a 0d array is only supported if the itemsize is unchanged
```

Earlier `view` often required a tweak in the dimensions.  I suspect that with recent changes to handling of structured arrays (most evident when indexing several fields at once), this error is a result, either intentionally or not.

In the whole array case it changed the 1d, 4 field array into a 1d, 4 element array, (1,) to (4,).  But changing the element, goes from () to (4,).

In the past I have recommended `tolist` as the surest way around problem with `view` (and `astype`):

```
In [274]: arr[0].tolist()
Out[274]: (105.0, 34.0, 145.0, 217.0)
In [279]: list(arr[0].tolist())
Out[279]: [105.0, 34.0, 145.0, 217.0]
In [280]: np.array(arr[0].tolist())
Out[280]: array([105.,  34., 145., 217.])
```

`item` is also a good way of pulling an element out of its numpy structure:

```
In [281]: arr[0].item()
Out[281]: (105.0, 34.0, 145.0, 217.0)
```

The result from `tolost` and `item` is a tuple.

You worry about speed.  But you are just converting one element. It's one thing to worry about the speed when using `tolist` on a 1000 item array, quite another when working with 1 element.

```
In [283]: timeit arr[0]
131 ns ± 1.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [284]: timeit arr[0].tolist()
1.25 µs ± 11.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [285]: timeit arr[0].item()
1.27 µs ± 2.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [286]: timeit arr.tolist()
493 ns ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [287]: timeit arr.view('f4')
1.74 µs ± 18.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

You could index the element in a way that doesn't reduce the dimension to 0 (not that it helps much with speed):

```
In [288]: arr[[0]].view('f4')
Out[288]: array([105.,  34., 145., 217.], dtype=float32)
In [289]: timeit arr[[0]].view('f4')
6.54 µs ± 15.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [290]: timeit arr[0:1].view('f4')
2.63 µs ± 105 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [298]: timeit arr[0][None].view('f4')
4.28 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

`view` still requires a change in shape;  consider a big array:

```
In [299]: arrs = np.repeat(arr, 10000)
In [301]: arrs.view('f4')
Out[301]: array([105.,  34., 145., ...,  34., 145., 217.], dtype=float32)
In [303]: arrs.shape
Out[303]: (10000,)
In [304]: arrs.view('f4').shape
Out[304]: (40000,)
```

The view is still 1d, where as we'd probably want a (10000,4) shaped 2d array.

A better view change:

```
In [306]: arrs.view(('f4',4))
Out[306]: 
array([[105.,  34., 145., 217.],
       [105.,  34., 145., 217.],
       [105.,  34., 145., 217.],
       ...,
       [105.,  34., 145., 217.],
       [105.,  34., 145., 217.],
       [105.,  34., 145., 217.]], dtype=float32)
In [307]: _.shape
Out[307]: (10000, 4)
```

This works with the 1 element array, whether 1d or 0d:

```
In [308]: arr.view(('f4',4))
Out[308]: array([[105.,  34., 145., 217.]], dtype=float32)
In [309]: _.shape
Out[309]: (1, 4)
In [310]: arr[0].view(('f4',4))
Out[310]: array([105.,  34., 145., 217.], dtype=float32)
In [311]: _.shape
Out[311]: (4,)
```

This was suggested in one of the answers in your link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171321/901925

Contrary to your comment there, it works for me:

```
In [312]: arr[0].view((np.float32, len(arr.dtype.names)))
Out[312]: array([105.,  34., 145., 217.], dtype=float32)
In [313]: np.__version__
Out[313]: '1.14.0'
```

---

With the edit:

```
In [84]: arr = np.array([(105.0, 34.0, 145.0, 217.0)], dtype=[('a', 'f4'), ('b','f4'), ('c', 'f4'), ('d', 'f4')])
In [85]: arr2 = arr[['a', 'b']]
In [86]: arr2
Out[86]: 
array([(105., 34.)],
      dtype={'names':['a','b'], 'formats':['<f4','<f4'], 'offsets':[0,4], 'itemsize':16})

In [87]: arr2.view(('f4',2))
...
ValueError: Changing the dtype to a subarray type is only supported if the total itemsize is unchanged
```

Note that the `arr2` `dtype` includes an `offsets` value.  In a recent numpy version, multiple field selection has changed.  It is now a true view, preserving the original data - all of it, not just the selected fields.  The itemsize is unchanged:

```
In [93]: arr.itemsize
Out[93]: 16
In [94]: arr2.itemsize
Out[94]: 16
```

`arr.view(('f4',4)` and `arr2.view(('f4',4))` produce the same thing.

So you can't `view` (change dtype) a partial set of the fields.  You have to first take the `view` of the whole array, and then select rows/columns, or work with `tolist`.

I'm using `1.14.0`.  Release notes for `1.14.1` says:

> The change in 1.14.0 that multi-field indexing of structured arrays returns a
>   view instead of a copy has been reverted but remains on track for NumPy 1.15.
>   Affected users should read the 1.14.1 Numpy User Guide section
>   "basics/structured arrays/accessing multiple fields" for advice on how to
>   manage this transition.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields

This is still under development.  That doc mentions a `repack_fields` function, but that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I've realized that I didn't pose my problem correctly. You are right, the solution in my OP does indeed not result in an error in my given example. I posed the example incorrectly. Very sorry for that! I updated the example with a slight modification. Now it both represents my actual use case and unfortunately definitely throws the error :/

Comment: Due to recent changes in mutlifield selection, you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edited answer, and thanks for pointing me towards the relevant documentation! If I should have looked more thoroughly. I guess I'll resort to converting to a list for now and then see what NumPy 1.15 brings.

Comment: Version 1.17 implements the new multi field view approach.  Read the docs and release notes.