# How can I assign slices of one structured Numpy array to another?

Tags: arrays, numpy, slice, structured-array

I have two numpy structured arrays `arr1`, `arr2`.

`arr1` has fields `['f1','f2','f3']`.

`arr2` has fields `['f1','f2','f3','f4']`.

I.e.:

```
arr1 = [[f1_1_1,  f2_1_1,  f3_1_1 ],    arr2 = [[f1_2_1,  f2_2_1,  f3_2_1,  f4_2_1 ],
        [f1_1_2,  f2_1_2,  f3_1_2 ],            [f1_2_2,  f2_2_2,  f3_2_2,  f4_2_2 ],
        ...                        ,            ...                                 ,
        [f1_1_N1, f2_1_N1, f3_1_N1]]            [f1_2_N2, f2_2_N2, f3_2_N2, f4_2_N2]]
```

I want to assign various slices of `arr1` to the corresponding slice of `arr2` (slices in the indexes and in the fields).
See below for the various cases.

From answers I found (to *related*, but not exactly the same, questions) it seemed to me that the only way to do it is assigning one slice at a time, for a single field, i.e., something like

```
arr2['f1'][0:1] = arr1['f1'][0:1]
```

(and I can confirm this works), looping over all source fields in the slice.

**Is there a way to assign all intended source fields in the slice at a time?**

---

I mean to assign, say, the elements `x` in the image

**Case 1** (only some fields in `arr1`)

```
arr1 = [[  x   ,    x   ,  f3_1_1 ],    arr2 = [[  x   ,    x   ,  f3_2_1,  f4_2_1 ],
        [  x   ,    x   ,  f3_1_2 ],            [  x   ,    x   ,  f3_2_2,  f4_2_2 ],
        ...                        ,            ...                                 ,
        [f1_1_N1, f2_1_N1, f3_1_N1]]            [f1_2_N2, f2_2_N2, f3_2_N2, f4_2_N2]]
```

**Case 2** (all fields in `arr1`)

```
arr1 = [[  x   ,    x   ,    x    ],    arr2 = [[  x   ,    x   ,    x   ,  f4_2_1 ],
        [  x   ,    x   ,    x    ],            [  x   ,    x   ,    x   ,  f4_2_2 ],
        ...                        ,            ...                                 ,
        [f1_1_N1, f2_1_N1, f3_1_N1]]            [f1_2_N2, f2_2_N2, f3_2_N2, f4_2_N2]]
```

**Case 3** 

`arr1` has fields `['f1','f2','f3','f5']`.

`arr2` has fields `['f1','f2','f3','f4']`.

Assign a slice of `['f1','f2','f3']`

---

Sources:

[Python Numpy Structured Array (recarray) assigning values into slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058602/python-numpy-structured-array-recarray-assigning-values-into-slices)

[Convert a slice of a structured array to regular NumPy array in NumPy 1.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028309/convert-a-slice-of-a-structured-array-to-regular-numpy-array-in-numpy-1-14)

Comment: Multiple field indexing changed around version `1.16`, so earlier answers might not apply.  Review the docs.

Comment: @hpaulj - Very relevant piece of information, I will read it. In the meantime, would you say the answer to the question is Yes or No?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for example like that:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([('Rex', 9, 81.0), ('Fido', 3, 27.0)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])
y = np.array([('Carl', 10, 75.0), ('Joe', 7, 76.0)], dtype=[('name2', 'U10'), ('age2', 'i4'), ('weight', 'f4')])

print(x[['name', 'age']])
print(y[['name2', 'age2']])

# multiple field indexing
y[['name2', 'age2']] = x[['name', 'age']]

print(y[['name2', 'age2']])

# you can also use slicing if you want specific parts or the size does not match
y[:1][['name2', 'age2']] = x[1:][['name', 'age']]

print(y[:][['name2', 'age2']])
```

The names field names can be different, I am not sure about the dtypes and if there is (down)casting.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#assignment-from-other-structured-arrays

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields

Comment: The `[:]` aren't necessary.  You should demonstrate how it works with multiple field indexing.