# Convert structured Numpy array into a normal array

Tags: python, numpy, opencl

I have a numpy array with the `dtype.names` as:

```
('s0', 's1', 's2', 's3')
```

**What steps would I follow to revert the numpy array `dtype` to np.float32?**

I obtain the numpy array ('s0', 's1', 's2', 's3') from:

```
    import pyopencl as cl
    import pyopencl.array as cl_array
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.misc import imread, imsave
    import math
    import os
    import PIL.Image
    import cv2

    os.environ['PYOPENCL_COMPILER_OUTPUT'] = '1'

    #produces numpy array of the structures
    # -> ('s0', 's1', 's2', 's3') and shape (image_width,image_height, image_depth). 
    def process_image(path_to_image, padding):
        rgb_image = PIL.Image.open(path_to_image)
        rgba_image = rgb_image.convert('RGBA')
        im_src = np.array(rgba_image).astype(dtype=np.float32)
        print(im_src.shape)
        return im_src.astype(dtype=cl_array.vec.float4)
```

`dtype=cl_array.vec.float4` bundles 4 `np.float32` into `(np.float32,np.float32,np.float32,np.float32)`

The `image_depth` is 4:

I tried this:

```
vector_float4= process_image('image.jpg',0)
result = np.array(vector_float4.tolist())
```

`result` has a shape of `(width, height, 4, 4)`. I expected `(width, height, 4)`.

I am looking at this answer: [Convert structured array to regular NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957380/convert-structured-array-to-regular-numpy-array)

Comment: For numpy arrays, the `.astype` method is usually sufficient to convert between the numpy `dtypes`, e.g. `float`, `np.float16`, `np.uint8`.  This doesn't necessarily apply to `cl/cv` types.  For example, I don't know how the `cl_array.vec.float4` relates to numpy dtypes.  numpy `tolist()` creates a list (nested) of Python scalar elements (floats, integers).  `np.array` can process most such lists (you may want to add a `dtype`).  The `tolist` route may be most robust, but it tends to be slowest.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.