# why is numpy returning a 1-d array here?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to read a numpy array from a big file of binary data.  Each binary record contains 7330 floats, followed by a long I want to ignore, and then an int.  I create a dtype as follows:

```
dt = [(str(n),'f4') for n in range(7330)]
dt += [('junk','i8'), ('label','i4')]
```

and then read the file via

```
d = np.fromfile(file_name,dtype=np.dtype(dt))
```

It works, but I get back a one-dimensional array or records instead of the 2-D array I want.  Somewhat more specifically, I get back an array with `d.shape=(58134,)` `d[0]` of type `numpy.void` and `len(d[0])=7332` (7330 floats, the long I will ignore, and the int).  I want an array of shape `(58134,7332)`.

I can't d.reshape(-1,7332) because d is one dimensional, and I wind up converting it via the ugly and somewhat absurd

```
nparray = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d).to_numpy()
```

which seems just ridiculous.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample of the 1D array you get and what it should look like instead so that we cn better understand the problem

Comment: what is the difference between a 1-D structured array `(n, )` and a two-dimensional `(n, 1)` array of records except for the redundant axis? Seems like the sane thing to do, if you really want `(n, 1)` then just reshape it.

Comment: `dtype` is the "type" of a single "element". Each "element" in your array has the information of 7330 floats, a long and an int, but it is still just an "element" of the resulting structured array.

Comment: @darcamo: That's exactly right, of course.  I guess my question should have been "how do I make this a 2-D array" instead of "why is this a 1-D array".  :)

Comment: Maybe something like this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957380/convert-structured-array-to-regular-numpy-array

Comment: `dt = [('data', 'f4', 7330), ('junk','i8'), ('label','i4')]` might also be useful.  It will create 3 fields.  `arr['data']` should then be the desired 2d array of floats.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that numpy.lib.recfunctions.structured_to_unstructured does exactly this.  Thanks to darcamo for pointing me in that direction.